# Ошибка при запуске приложения на Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:p0031firstproject:clean, :p0031firstproject:generateDebugSources, :p0031firstproject:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :p0031firstproject:mockableAndroidJar, :p0031firstproject:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :p0031firstproject:assembleDebug]
:p0031firstproject:clean
:p0031firstproject:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:p0031firstproject:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:p0031firstproject:checkDebugManifest
:p0031firstproject:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:p0031firstproject:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
:p0031firstproject:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
:p0031firstproject:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library
:p0031firstproject:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
:p0031firstproject:prepareDebugDependencies
:p0031firstproject:compileDebugAidl
:p0031firstproject:compileDebugRenderscript
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugBuildConfig
:p0031firstproject:mergeDebugShaders
:p0031firstproject:compileDebugShaders
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugAssets
:p0031firstproject:mergeDebugAssets
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugResources
:p0031firstproject:mergeDebugResources
:p0031firstproject:processDebugManifest
:p0031firstproject:processDebugResources
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugSources
:p0031firstproject:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:p0031firstproject:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:p0031firstproject:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:p0031firstproject:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:p0031firstproject:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:p0031firstproject:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:p0031firstproject:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:p0031firstproject:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:p0031firstproject:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:p0031firstproject:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:p0031firstproject:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:p0031firstproject:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:p0031firstproject:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:p0031firstproject:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:p0031firstproject:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:p0031firstproject:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:p0031firstproject:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:p0031firstproject:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':p0031firstproject:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3 mins 9.756 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы не весь лог ошибки выложили и где-то выше в нём указана ваша конкретная ошибка.

Comment: Это только с этим проектом? Студия 2 версии? Появилось после добавления к-л либы? Не хватает инфы.

Comment: Тут постотрите http://stackoverflow.com/a/29731816/3212712

Comment: Android Studio 2.1, JRE - 1.8.0_91. Недавно установил студио. Первое приложение

Comment: Вторя студия аццки глючная. И попробуйте JRE на 1.7 сменить.

Comment: JRE на 1.7 сменить как?)

Comment: Скачать нужную версию и где-то в настройках студии указать путь к ней, вместо 1.8

Comment: Вот тут тоже пишут, что дело в 1.8 (т.е в восьмой яве) ибо андроид только в 7-ую умеет (она же 1.7)

Comment: установил и поменял на jre 1.7. Внес изменения в grad файлы. А там уже другие ошибки. Подскажите какие grad файлы нужно отредактировать

Comment: Как я могу подсказать если не вижу никаких фалов и никаких ошибок?..

Answer (score 1):

Gradle просто надо взять посвежее, это он ошибку выбрасывает в вашем случае.

Android Studio 2 требует как минимум Gradle 2.10, я пользуюсь 2.12 сейчас.

**P.S.** версия JDK тут похоже ни причем. Мы же решаем эту проблему:

> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file.